# Closed form of $\sum_{k=0}^p \binom{k+m-1}{m-1}?$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

> **Question**: Is there a closed form for the summation
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^p \binom{k+m-1}{m-1}?$$

By writing out the summation, we have 
$$\binom{m-1}{m-1} + \binom{m}{m-1} + \binom{m+1}{m-1}+...+\binom{p+m-2}{m-1}+\binom{p+m-1}{m-1}$$
$$ = 1 + m + \frac{m(m+1)}{2} + \frac{m(m+1)(m+2)}{3!}+...+\frac{m(m+1)...(m+(k-1))}{k!}+...+\frac{m(m+1)...(m+(p-1))}{p!}.$$
However, I do not see a closed form for it.

Comment: $\dbinom{p+m}{m}$. See the [hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).

Comment: Compare with Pascal's triangle to see hockey stick identity showing up. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the summation $$\sum_{k=0}^p \binom{k+m-1}{m-1},$$ make a change of variable by letting $i = k + m - 1$.  When $k = 0$, $i = m-1$; when $k = p$, $i = p+m-1$.  The required summation becomes $$\sum_{i=m-1}^{p+m-1} \binom{i}{m-1}.$$  Apply the [Hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity) $${\sum _{i=r}^{n}{i \choose r}={n+1 \choose r+1}}$$ with $n = p+m-1$ and $r = m - 1$, so that $$\sum_{k=0}^p \binom{k+m-1}{m-1} = \sum_{i=m-1}^{p+m-1} \binom{i}{m-1} = {p+m \choose m}.$$

Comment: @Isham Thanks for spotting out my mistake.  Typo fixed.

Comment: yw +1 for your nice answer Gnu